# Does anyone know where can I get this part?

Tags: chevrolet, aveo

I have a *Chevy Aveo 2008 1.6L LT* (Made in Korea 5/07) it’s an old motor. I just need the 4 way connection. I know they discontinued the part but I just need the metal conjunction. Whole part number is 96474643 (PVC Valve Hose) I’ve recently fix the car little by little and it has a sentimental value for me. Could anybody help me find it? A mechanic sort of helped me with uniweld for it to stop dripping water since it’s all rusty, he also tried to create a bridge connecting the water together but for some reason my car was not speeding over 40. Here’s a picture so you guys can have an idea of what I’m talking about. [image: Thats the 4 way connection I’m looking for to get my car going]

Comment: Have you asked at the parts counter of a Chevrolet dealership?

Comment: Yes I have, it’s out of stock since it’s discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a car junkyard that has one of these vehicles, and see if the yard operator will sell you parts from the junked/wrecked car.

If you can't find such a vehicle, or the yard operator won't sell parts from it, or the part is missing, take the defective part you already have to a mechanic and ask what local workshop can make such a part.

Comment: Sure will…thanks